# Reading bits from UDP packet in Java

Tags: java, sockets, dns, udp, bit

I have the following code to receive UDP packets:

```
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(port));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

    while(true)
    {
        socket.receive(packet);

        byte[] data = packet.getData();

        packet.setLength(buffer.length);

    }
```

The datagram I am receiving is from using the dig command with localhost to make a DNS query. (dig @localhost -p 1234 test.com) I know that the DNS query format looks like the table shown on this site: http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/dns.htm

I want to be able to read individual bits from the datagram to see the different codes (like QR code and such) and read the queries. I understand how this is done in C since I can read individual bits there, but I would like to do this in Java. I am having a hard time figuring out how to parse the datagram effectively since I receive an array of bytes and packet.getData() prints out garbage values into the console. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Strange code. Do you realize that `buffer == data`? And that you shoild reset the length *before* each receive?

Answer (score 0):

You can check bits in a byte using a mask:

```
    int bit0 = b & 0x01;
    int bit1 = b & 0x02;
    int bit2 = b & 0x04;
    ...
    int bit7 = b & 0x80;
```